# Git commit is hanging, what should I do?

Tags: git

I did a large initial git commit from an existing code base and for about an hour the screen is hung while doing "create mode". It looks like this (note some parts are blacked out to preserve anonymity):

[image]

What should I do?

----------**UPDATE**

I pressed the return key and the command prompt appeared. Is this some weird quirk that the user has to press the return after git printouts?

Comment: Do you have a full file system? If so, maybe you can delete or move some unrelated files to free space?

Comment: For what it's worth, those messages come out *after* Git has made the new commit, when it compares the new commit to the previous one. (Since this is the first commit, it's comparing the new commit to an empty tree.)

Comment: Can you show ***exactly*** how you invoked `git commit`? Was it `git commit` or `git commit -m`? If it's the former, `git` may have had trouble bringing up an editor for you to write your commit message into.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably entered selection mode in the Windows command prompt (by clicking to place the cursor), which pauses all commands until you leave it.